# aws codeBuild buildspec.yml example for github

Tags: github, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use AWS CodeBuild for building my code from github. These are the steps I followed so far,

- 1) Created a windows docker image with all the pre-req software
  needed (git, npm, node.js etc) and pushed to Amazon ECS.
- 2)Created a project in AWS CodeBuild using
- a) github as the source (What to build)
- b) docker image created in Step 1 (How to build)

  I setup buildspec.yml as below:

> ## env:
>
> ```
> #variables:    
> #parameter-store:    
> phases:
> #install:     
> #pre_build:    
> build:
> commands:
>     - git clone https://github.com/OrgName/RepName.git "c:\www\localfolder"     
> #post_build:    
> #artifacts:
>  #files:
> ```

But this is always failing during DOWNLOAD_SOURCE STEP saying "CodeBuild is experiencing Issues"

Please suggest how to setup buildspec.yml for github clone\fetch\checkout purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you encountered may not be related to git clone\fetch\checkout failure. The build could also fail at "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE" step if CodeBuild failed/timed out when pulling the Windows Docker image; especially when the image is large.

Workarounds you can try:

1) use the windows image provided by CodeBuild and install the pre-req software during the install phase. (you will need to update your buildspec.yml)

OR

2) use a BUILD_GENERAL1_LARGE instance. maybe you will need to increase the timeout too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. During the build process, the SUBMITTED and PROVISIONING step both passed though PROVISIONING step took around 10 minutes and then the next step "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE" is getting failed. I am just wondering at what point codebuild uses github source (details provided like: sourceprovider, public repository url etc). any sample buildspec.yml which is used to pull in specific branches from GIT and building an output artifact could be helpful. Thanks again.